# IE9, HTML5: Embedding HTML5 page into page with no doctype

Tags: internet-explorer, html, iframe, internet-explorer-9, doctype

I have an HTML page without `DOCTYPE` declaration. In IE9 it is rendered in the quirks mode. Now I have to embed an HTML5 document into that document. All these happen in IE9.

I tried using iframe, but it seems that the browser ignores `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration of the child document and it gets rendered in quirks mode.

How to embed an HTML5 document into HTML which doesn't have doctype declaration. Should work under IE9.

Comment: Use [XHTML5 markup](http://debeterevormgever.nl/en/articles/html5-elements-ie-without-javascript/example-xhtml) for the HTML5 page to avoid the doctype conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Use the XML serialization of HTML5 for the embedded page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
      <!--...-->
    </head>

    <body>
      <!--...-->
    </body>
</html>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV0km.gif):

[image: Embedded Doctype]

Comment: This does not work. There is no way to host page with new document model inside iframe of a page with older document model. [At least according to MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vet6/). Added screencap above.

Comment: So solution is hosting within a flash animation? Btw, your image shows FF, not IE9, and I don't see some distinct HTML5 features that demonstrate this works.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević Just try the jsfiddle for yourself.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević That is not Flash animation, right click it and open in a new window.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević The solution is hosting an XHTML5 document within an object tag. In this case, saxonica.com. The XML processor is separated from the HTML processor of the parent. It could also be SVG, VML, or XSLT.